# External input in dash plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash, zeromq

In my specific case I am looking to have zeromq (https://zeromq.org) messages trigger a callback in dash (and the dash callback be able to trigger sending messages similarly). Generically this is having dash triggered by external input; is there anything like this or similar that works in dash?

Answer (score 0):

Talking from experience, I have used a dash-django-redis-celery hybrid setup. In summary, we had celery run jobs periodically, these jobs would in turn update the database, and then in dash having a `dcc.interval` component to update the dashboard and if the data has been changed, this would trigger a callback of some kind that is dependent on the data. So yes, I imagine this could be possible with zeroMQ with a similar approach, but you'll need to use a backend framework like django to coordinate and wrap this all up which I can't say for sure is.

If you are not too eager on using ZeroMQ, then redis+celery is great with Django, and there is a [nice package](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash) for building django-dash applications which is actively updated.

Comment: This is essentially a two level operation with a poll in both directions (write to db -> pull from db), instead of a single eventloop call (zmq or dash). I had already considered this option as I have a db in the stack but it does not seem like a nice solution at all and probably a bit of an anti pattern - what if the DB is not up for example?